# How to change Aspect order?

Tags: java, spring-aop

I have 2 aspects.

```
@Aspect
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class Aspect1{}
```

and

```
@Aspect
public class Aspect2{}
```

When I run the app, Aspect1 gets executed before Aspect2. I don't have any control on project in which Aspect 2 is defined. I can make changes in Aspect1.Both the aspects have afterThrowing advice.
Can you suggest me how do i make Aspect2 run before Apsect 1?

Comment: Which types of advices are used in both aspects? `@Before`, `@After`, `@Around`? Please edit your question and provide more details. Best would be an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) reproducing the current problem and an explanation of the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `Aspect2` and implement `"org.springframework.core.Ordered"` interface.
You can override the method and return what order you want to set-

```
public int getOrder() {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with changing the pointcut defination of Aspect1. Now pointcut is defined on method declared inside Aspect 2. This makes Aspect2 run first then It throws Exceptions which is captured by Aspect1.